# Reason for \in positioning, and possible fix?

Tags: alignment, subscripts, displaystyle

All the tex layouts I've seen thus far produce something like:
[image]
In displaystyle the off-centering (or centering?) of the `\in` symbol isn't very noticable, however it is in scriptstyle. Also:
[image]
The same off-centering (or centering?) happens here. It also seems Scriptstyle discriminates between how much the different symbols are down-sized (this may just be incompetency of my eyes). Is this generally seen as a feature for visual clarity or a shortcoming of the tex-engine - and is there a possible fix?

When talking about the 'problem' and what I'm asking for a fix of - I'm talking about both the size-discrimination of scriptstyle and the off-centering (or centering?). Any clarity would be great, I realise I know little about typesetting:)

Kind regards

Edit: I was asked to provide a reference. I apologise this wasn't done before:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\text{Scriptstyle}:{\scriptstyle n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\text{Displaystyle}:n \in \mathbb{N}$ \\ \\
$\text{Scriptstyle}:{\scriptstyle n \geq 1$ and $\text{Displaystyle}:n \geq 1$
\end{document}
```

I hope this suffices.

Comment: By (long-standing) convention, mathbin and mathrel symbols are vertically aligned on the math axis -- the imaginary line that is visible for the position of a minus sign or a fraction line.  This is not really a personal preference of the font designer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes but... unlike `\mathop` where tex will position the symbol to align on the math axis, `\mathbin` and `\mathrel` are placed on the baseline so any alignment is a feature of the font, not tex. Also of course the size is a choice of the font design, especially in the smaller cm fonts `\in` is quite large with noticable depth, if you try with for example `stix2` `\in` sits on the baseline in scriptsize and display size. (well for stix2 the script font is simply scaled so naturally the relative depth does not change)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Thanks for setting me straight.  It seems that stix2 was not properly tested before release, so this problem should be reported.  (I find this incredibly frustrating.)

Comment: I don't see any problem with stix here, it is the cm one that is a bit strange with cmsy7 having noticeably bigger depth than cmsy10 @barbarabeeton

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Okay, I'll send it by the vetting crew,

Comment: @barbarabeeton no way cm can change after all this time, it is what it is

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Not to be changed, but a record is maintained and periodically a public report is issued,

Comment: @barbarabeeton ok but I wouldn't say anything's wrong, I just don't like the shape much, as I said in the answer it's all down to the font designers choices.

Comment: I added a "nobug" entry at https://tug.org/texmfbug/nobug.html#symbolalignment ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As always it would be much clearer if you provided a test document.

Unlike `\mathop` positioned characters such as `\sum` which are vertically centred on the math axis by TeX, these are (presumably, although you don't say) `\mathbin` and `\mathrel` atoms. As such their vertical position is not adjusted at all by TeX and they are simply placed on the baseline as normal characters.

So the size and visual alignment of the character is out of TeX's control, it is purely a feature of the glyph shape as determined by the font designer. You have not shown which font you are using.

With cm and ams fints at 10pt (and 7pt scriptsize) you get

[image]

so at displaysize the fonts used ar

`.\OML/cmm/m/it/10` for letters and`\OMS/cmsy/m/n/10` for the symbols, and the same with `/7` for scriptstyle.

```
\expandafter\show\expanded{\expandafter\the\csname OML/cmm/m/it/10\endcsname}
\expandafter\show\expanded{\expandafter\the\csname OMS/cmsy/m/n/10\endcsname}
\expandafter\show\expanded{\expandafter\the\csname OML/cmm/m/it/7\endcsname}
\expandafter\show\expanded{\expandafter\the\csname OMS/cmsy/m/n/7\endcsname}
```

would show that these are the design size fonts cmmi10 cmsy10 at display size and cmmi7 and cmsy7 at scriptsize

Comment: Apologies, the code for the document is now provided. The compiler is pdflatex, if this makes any difference. I'm not sure about the font (I think it's just cm), but I assume this has to do with the document class.

Comment: @studyingmathematics I'd added an example.

Comment: my example using same fonts so same applies, this is just how the designer (Knuth) wanted the symbols to look, TeX has no information about the character shape

Comment: Thanks. I don't know if I dare set my personal preference agains Donald Knuth's. Do you know if there is a design principle which this is motivated by, or just Knuth's personal preference?

Comment: @studyingmathematics personally I think the cm `\in` is a bit big but there are by now lots of fonts, just choose one you like (you could of course define `\in` to be some custom scaled. raised/lowered version of the original but it's all very subjective)